Seeking recommendations for R Packages for Multilevel Mediation Analysis with Binary Mediator
I am conducting a research study and aim to investigate the relationship between dietary habits (independent variable) and academic performance (dependent variable) of adolescents, with extracurricular activity participation as a mediator.
Here are the specifics of my study:
Outcome (dependent variable): Academic performance (continuous) [measured by academic_score]
Exposure (independent variable): Dietary habits [diet_quality, meal_frequency] categorized into three groups (low, medium, high)
Mediator: Extracurricular activity participation [activity_sports, activity_arts] (binary: yes[1]/no[0])
Covariates: Age, BMI, socioeconomic status (SES), sleep duration (sleep_duration), survey wave (survey_wave)
Levels: Survey wave and school district
Subgroups: I am particularly interested in examining the model separately for boys (gender=1) and girls (gender=2).
Research Question: Does extracurricular activity participation attenuate the relationship between dietary habits and academic performance of adolescents?
Given that my mediator is a binary variable and the model includes multiple levels (survey waves and school districts), I am seeking recommendations on appropriate R packages that can handle multilevel mediation analysis with a binary mediator.
Can anyone suggest the best R packages or methods to use for this kind of analysis? Specifically, I need to:
Accommodate binary mediation variables in a multilevel mediation framework.
Analyze the data separately for different subgroups (boys and girls).
Properly account for covariates and the hierarchical structure of the data.

I don't think you necessarily need specialised software to conduct mediation analyses with multilevel (ie., mixed effects) models. Any software package that fits mixed effects models should do - for example lme4.
Another idea is to use a structural equation modelling approach using something that supports random effects. I think lavaan has this capability (via a clustering option). But a more sophisticated approach could be achieved with MPlus which has an R front end (you do need a MPlus license though!)

Analyze the data separately for different subgroups (boys and girls)

That is not normally a good idea as it results in a large loss of statistical power - it's better to include gender as variable that you then also use in an interaction to see how things differ between boys and girls.

+1 What is different about Mplus and lavaan is that you pull it all off in a single model. Using lme4 you would need to run a model for the mediator and model for the outcome, plus some post-estimation work for the indirect effect. Mplus is the best program for this type of analysis, IMO, but is also something you have to pay for. The free version limits you to something like 7 variables.
